# Cull a text field by certain amount of characters while making sure not to cut off words

Tags: php, string, recursion, trim

So I'm running into what is probably a pretty common problem when creating dynamic websites that pull page information from a database. Say you have a slider on the front page that shows the 8 most recent blog/story posts. The server grabs the title, caption, and text fields for each, but we don't want to return the full text of the article to the browser, that would be wasteful. So what I'm guessing you would do is cut the text field off at a certain amount of characters using a recursive function, except I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
$string = strip_tags("<p>Jackson expects to practice on Wednesday for the first time since getting hurt in a season-opening game agains the Chicago Bears. The teams medical advisor says his sprained ankle has healed fast then expected, although he warns to err on the side of caution.</p><p>Coach Andy Reid is optimistic he can get Jackson ready in time for next Monday's square off vs the Detroit Lions, though he states that he doesn't want to take the risk of loosing him for the start of the playoffs in 3 weeks.</p>");
$count = 0;

echo $string."<br />";

function trim_string($string, $max_length, $search_char){
    global $count;
    $pos = strripos($string, $search_char);
    $new_string = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    $length = strlen($new_string);  

    if($length > $max_length){      
        $count++;
        trim_string($new_string, 120, ' ');
    }else{
        return $new_string; 
    }   
}

$trimmed_string = trim_string($string, 120, ' ');

echo $count."<br />".substr_count($string, ' ')."<br />".$trimmed_string;
```

As you can see I'm trying to debug. Count returns 67, while the original number of occurrences is 86, so I know it's working, but nothing echo's out for $trimmed_string.

If anyone has any ideas or a better way of doing this sort of thing, lemme know!

Comment: I just had the function echo out the new string right before it calls itself again and know that it's indeed working, but I don't understand why it doesn't return this string once it's shortened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily need to be recursive.

```
function trim_string($string, $max_length, $search_char)
{
    $string = substr($string, 0, $max_length);
    $last_index = strrpos($string, $search_char);
    return substr($string, 0, $last_index);
}
```

That's a basic idea. It might give you a blank space at the end if you are chopping somewhere that's not a space or something.

And also, it's not echoing because you need to return the recursion.

```
if($length > $max_length){      
    $count++;
    return trim_string($new_string, 120, ' ');
}else{
    return $new_string; 
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way, as well as the reason why my value wasn't returning for the recursion. Thanks!

Comment: Question though, I wonder, are some of these string functions built into PHP recursive in and of themselves? Also, I would think it would, in a large scale setting, probably make sense to run this function once when storing in the DB and keeping this smaller string in a separate field. This additional DB overhead is probably far more efficient then having to run a function like this on each page call, and far more efficient then having to send the full article's  text to the client to run a similar function on the users end.

Comment: Yeah, it would make sense to store in the db over running something like this, especially in a loop. However, if you write dynamic pages to flat text on update then it doesn't really matter. I would store in db AND write to flat text personally. I always prefer to serve pre-rendered html over on the fly dynamic where possible.

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i would not do a *recursive* function **but** a
**simple function**
which will do this

- explode " " yes it's a one space
- after count charcter of each strgin after

  ..let me show you

  $array = explode(" ",$string);
  //lets say

  $max_length =50;
  $output="";
  foreach($array as $value ){
  if(strlen($output.$value) > $max_length) break;
  else $output.=$value;
  }

  echo $ouput;

what do you think ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I follow your code so well, but this goes back to what I asked above. A function like explode must certainly be a recursive function of sorts, no? Exploding all of these parts into an array and then iterating through the array seems like extra work for the CPU though. I'm no computer science major though haha but I like thinking about these things.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one** for size:

```
/**
* Keeps a (maximum or minimum) number of characters from a string.
* Will not break words in the process.
*
* If $RightBound === true the $Length is the maximum allowed.
* If $RightBound === false the $Length is the minimum allowed.
* 
* @param string $String
* @param int $Length
* @param bool $RightBound
* @return string
*/
function ChunkWordsByLength($String, $Length, $Bound = true){
    if(!is_string($String)){
        trigger_error('$String must be a string.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_numeric($Length) or (($Length = intval($Length)) < 1)){
        trigger_error('$Length must be a positive integer.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if(strlen($String) <= $Length){
        return $String;
    }
    if(($Bound !== 'left') and ($Bound !== 'right')){
        trigger_error('$Bound must be "left" or "right".', E_USER_WARNING);
    }
    if($Bound === 'right'){
        $Pattern = "^.{0,{$Length}}\\b";
    }else{
        $Pattern = "^.{{$Length}}.*?\\b";
    }
    return preg_match("~{$Pattern}~", $String, $Slices) ? trim($Slices[0]) : false;
}

/**
* Alias of ChunkWordsByLength($String, $Length, 'right').
* 
* @param string $String
* @param int $Length
* @return string
*/
function ChunkWordsByLengthMax($String, $Length){
    return ChunkWordsByLength($String, $Length, 'right');
}

/**
* Alias of ChunkWordsByLength($String, $Length, 'left').
* 
* @param string $String
* @param int $Length
* @return string
*/
function ChunkWordsByLengthMin($String, $Length){
    return ChunkWordsByLength($String, $Length, 'left');
}
```

**It uses RegExp** and allows you to set Length to a minimum or maximum of characters. It's also a lot shorter but I added error checking as I'm using it too.

1. When **Bound is 'right'**, it brings just before the Length.
2. When **Bound is 'left'**, it breaks just after the Length.

Use like this:

```
var_dump(ChunkWordsByLengthMax($String, 120));
var_dump(ChunkWordsByLengthMin($String, 120));
```

*Hope it helps.*